# como retornar o conteúdo de um json no flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Gostaria de retornar o conteúdo de um arquivo json que esta na minha maquina em um endpoint,basicamente eu tenho um arquivo com citações e gostaria de retorna o conteúdo desse arquivo em um endpoint,porem não consegui achar um tutoria que não seja com o método "POST".